# Xcode: how can I run custom build phases only if any Swift file is changed?

Tags: xcode, xcode14

I'd like to run `swiftlint` automatically during build but only if any `.swift` file has been changed. I tried to specify

```
$(SRCROOT)/**.swift
```

for "Input Files" but it complains that the phase "will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs". When I specify the same for "Output Files" the warning goes away but the phase is never run.